# Synchronize lists

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have two 2d lists:

```
list1 = Transpose[{{1, 4, 7, 9, 4, 6, 7, 8, 3, 2}, 
                    {0.12, 0.19, 0.29, 0.39, 0.51, 0.62, 0.71, 0.80, 0.89, 0.99}}];

(*{{1, 0.12}, 
   {4, 0.19}, 
   {7, 0.29}, 
   {9, 0.39}, 
   {4, 0.51}, 
   {6, 0.62}, 
   {7, 0.71}, 
   {8, 0.8},  
   {3, 0.89}, 
   {2, 0.99}}*)

list2 = Transpose[{{3, 6, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 7, 4, 8}, 
                    {0.30, 0.40, 0.51, 0.62, 0.72, 0.79, 0.88, 0.98, 1.09, 1.2}}];

(*{{3, 0.3}, 
   {6, 0.4}, 
   {9, 0.51}, 
   {2, 0.62}, 
   {4, 0.72}, 
   {8, 0.79}, 
   {5, 0.88}, 
   {7, 0.98}, 
   {4, 1.09}, 
   {8, 1.2}}*)
```

I want to synchronize the two lists according to their second vector content.

The numbers in the second vector are in both lists increasing; the difference between two neighboured values is nearly "constant" in `list1[[All,2]]` and `list2[[All,2]]`, but slightly varying.

My code:

```
n = Flatten@Nearest[list1[[All, 2]], list2[[All, 2]]]

(*{0.29, 0.39, 0.51, 0.62, 0.71, 0.8, 0.89, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99}*)

p1 = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[Position[list1[[All, 2]], #] & /@ n]

(*{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}*)

result1 = list1[[p1]]

(*{{7, 0.29}, {9, 0.39}, {4, 0.51}, {6, 0.62}, {7, 0.71}, {8, 0.8}, {3, 0.89}, {2, 0.99}}*)

result2 = list2[[p1 - Min[p1] + 1]]

{{3, 0.3}, {6, 0.4}, {9, 0.51}, {2, 0.62}, {4, 0.72}, {8, 0.79}, {5, 0.88}, {7, 0.98}}

result = Transpose[{result1, result2}]

(*{{{7, 0.29}, {3, 0.3}}, 
   {{9, 0.39}, {6, 0.4}}, 
   {{4, 0.51}, {9, 0.51}}, 
   {{6, 0.62}, {2, 0.62}}, 
   {{7, 0.71}, {4, 0.72}}, 
   {{8, 0.8}, {8, 0.79}}, 
   {{3, 0.89}, {5, 0.88}}, 
   {{2, 0.99}, {7, 0.98}}}*)
```

Do you have another solution for this?

Comment: If you use instead `list1 = Transpose[{{1, 4, 7, 9, 10, 4, 6, 7, 8, 3, 2}, {0.12, 0.19, 0.29, 0.39, 0.39, 0.51, 0.62, 0.71, 0.80, 0.89, 0.99}}]` and `list2 = Transpose[{{3, 6, 9, 10, 2, 4, 8, 5, 7, 4, 8}, {0.30, 0.40, 0.40, 0.51, 0.62, 0.72, 0.79, 0.88, 0.98, 1.09, 1.2}}]` then the current 4 answer and your code yields 5 different results! Which is correct?

Comment: @Coolwater: The important information is: The numbers in the second vector are in both lists increasing; the difference between two neighboured values is nearly "constant" (see question). In my case the difference is about 0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a `Rule` to `Nearest`

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Transpose[{Nearest[list1[[All, 2]] -> list1,
                     list2[[All, 2]], 1][[All, 1]], list2}], First]
```

> {{{7, 0.29}, {3, 0.3}}, {{9, 0.39}, {6, 0.4}}, {{4, 0.51}, {9, 
>      0.51}}, {{6, 0.62}, {2, 0.62}}, {{7, 0.71}, {4, 0.72}}, {{8, 
>      0.8}, {8, 0.79}}, {{3, 0.89}, {5, 0.88}}, {{2, 0.99}, {7, 0.98}}}

Comment: I think I like this solution very much, also because it is extremely fast (see my comment to T.F) and does not need any manual input (-> 0.02). Your code needs 0.4 sec to process my real data https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wKP6yNcpyfcDc3VjZnOUlBNmc (`Dimensions[list1]=Dimensions[list2]={49421, 5}`) with: `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Transpose[{Nearest[list1[[All, 3]] -> list1, list2[[All, 3]], 1][[All, 1]], list2}], 
   First]; // AbsoluteTiming`

Answer (score 3):

Use `Gather`.

```
Select[Gather[Join[list1, list2], Abs[Last@#1 - Last@#2] < 0.02 &], Length@# == 2 &]
```

Comment: Great solution ...

Comment: Gather, GatherBy, Sort, SortBy, and Select are great tools to manipulate lists.

Comment: I tested you code with my "real data set" https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wKP6yNcpyfcDc3VjZnOUlBNmc (`Dimensions[list1]=Dimensions[list2]={49421, 5}`) . The following code `Select[Gather[Join[list1, list2], Abs[#1[[3]] - #2[[3]]] < 1000000 &], Length@# == 2 &]; // AbsoluteTiming` needs for 1000 lines 3.8 sec, for 2000 lines about 15 sec, for 3000 lines 36 sec, for 4000 lines 61 sec and so on. Unfortunately I am not able to process this way about 50000 lines. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

we can use `FixedPoint` with `Replace`

```
Cases[FixedPoint[Replace[{p___, {x_, y_}, q___, {w_, z_}, r___} /; 
 Abs[y - z] < 0.02 :> {p, {{x, y}, {w, z}}, q, r}], Join[list1, list2]],
{{_, _}, {_, _}}]

(* {{{7, 0.29}, {3, 0.3}}, {{9, 0.39}, {6, 0.4}}, {{4, 0.51}, {9,0.51}},
{{6, 0.62}, {2, 0.62}}, {{7, 0.71}, {4, 0.72}}, {{8,0.8}, {8, 0.79}},
{{3, 0.89}, {5, 0.88}}, {{2, 0.99}, {7, 0.98}}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. This is the first time that I learned about `FixedPoint` ...

Comment: @mrz you are very welcome. It is a handy construct. You can use it for expression convergence to a constant state

Answer (score 2):

```
 Cases[Partition[#, 2]& @ SortBy[Last] @ Join[list1, list2],
     {{_, a_}, {_, b_}} /; b - a < 0.02] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. The order of vector 1 and 2 should be exchanged at position 4 and in the last two elements

Comment: Oh yes, now I see - but there is no easy solution within the frame of my answer